# How to obtain solution of differential equation in this simple linear birth-death process?

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes

(Apologies for the poor title, I didn't know what what to type in)

I am having a problem with the second part of this question (an example question from a past stochastic course I took):

---

> Consider the simple linear birth and death process and the partial
>   diﬀerential equation
>
> $\frac{\partial G}{\partial t} = (λz − µ)(z − 1)\frac{\partial
> G}{\partial z}$
>
> satisﬁed by the p.g.f.
>
> $G(z, t) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} P(N(t) = j|N(0) = a)z^j$
>
> Deﬁne
>
> $m(t) = E[N(t)|N(0) = a]$ for $ t ≥ 0.$
>
> 1. By diﬀerentiating the partial diﬀerential equation partially with respect to z and then setting z = 1, show that m(t) satisﬁes the
>      diﬀerential equation
>
>    $\frac{dm}{dt} = (λ − µ)m $
> 2. Deduce an explicit expression for m(t).

---

The solution for part (1) is easy enough by noting that

$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial z \partial t} = [λ(z-1)+(λz − µ)]\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}+(λz − µ)(z − 1)\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial z^2}$

and at z = 1:

$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial z \partial t} |_{z=1} = (λ − µ)\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}$

Now, m(t) looks like the first derivative of the p.g.f. at z = 1 and so

$\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}|_{z=1} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}jP(N(t)=j|N(0)=a)z^{j-1}|_{z=1} = E[P(N(t)|N(0)=a)]=m(t)$

i.e.

$ m(t)=\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}|_{z=1}$

and so

$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial z \partial t} =\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\{\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}\} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \{m(t)\}= \frac{\partial m}{\partial t} = (\lambda-\mu)m$

as required.

**However, the solution in my notes for part (2) is given as $m(t) = ae^{(\lambda-\mu)t}$ where $m(0) = a$ but I can't figure out how to do that.**

Answer (score 1):

Just integrate directly:

$\frac{dm}{dt} = (\lambda -\mu) m$

$\int \frac{dm}{m} = \int (\lambda - \mu) \,dt$

$\ln m = (\lambda - \mu) t + C$ for some constant

$m = e^{(\lambda - \mu) t + C} = ae^{(\lambda - \mu) t}$ by solving for $C$ when $t=0$.